'Error running pod install' when I insert flutter_reactive_ble, In my macbook (intel chip)
Error in flutter when I tried  running my IOS app on my iphone.  I did not get this error for a specific app that I inserted flutter_reactive_ble or other apps too. How can I resolve that?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
